# Create "Composite Global Secondary Index" in dynamoDB

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I need to create a composite GSI based on 3 different fields and query the data. I cannot find any resource which can point me to the correct direction and usage of this. Would appreciate some help on how this can be achieved ?

The table is as below:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = TABLE_NAME)
public class MyTable {

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = NAME)
    private String name;
    
    private Person person;
    
}
```

Person.java

```
public class Person {
    
    private String name;
    private String age;
    private Gender gender; //Gender is an enum : MALE, FEMALE, OTHER
    private String occupation;
    .
    .
    .
    and so on

}
```

Do I need to create another object like `PersonV2` and then create an index on it or it should be done in a different way ?

APPROACH :

```
public class PersonV2 {
    
    private String name;
    private String age;
    private Gender gender;
}
```

and the my table will look like this ?

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = TABLE_NAME)
public class MyTable {

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = NAME)
    private String name;
    
    private Person person;
    
    @DynamoDBIndexHashKey(attributeName = MY_INDEX_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, globalSecondaryIndexName = MY_INDEX_NAME)
    private PersonV2 personV2;

    
}
```

Is this the correct way to handle this ?

Comment: What does it mean that you "do not have access to hashkey of the table"? You need to create a new field / column where you combine the required fields and then put a GSI on that.

Comment: @luk2302 I have edited the question. Also, added the approach that you suggested. Is that correct or I need to handle this differently ?